# Ad hoc distribution deploys to iOS 6.1 but not iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, ios5, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm having trouble distributing an app to ad hoc testers who use original iPads with iOS 5.1.1 using over-the-air distribution.  The app runs correctly on the 5.1 and 6.1 simulators. It works correctly on tethered iOS 5.1 original iPads and iOS 6.1 iPads.  OTA ad hoc downloads to 6.1 iPads work fine.  But the OTA ad hoc distribution to the original iPads fails, "Unable to Download Application".

I checked that the UDID is correct.

I tried wiping all the profiles from an 5.1 iPad.  The provisioning profile showed up after tethered download but the ad hoc profile didn't after the failed OTA download.  An ideas?

Thanks--

Answer (score 1):

The iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1 cannot handle the arm64 binary. Remove arm64 from the list of valid architectures for your Ad Hoc build. It will then install successfully. Your build will still run on new hardware and iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once before.  I had to delete the installed version of the app from the devices, restart the device, and then it worked.

You can also monitor the Console under `Organizer -> Device Name -> Console` and see what errors it reports while trying to install.

Comment: All I saw was this console error twice.  It also appears, but only once when successfully downloading to an iPad2.                         Apr  3 15:11:09 Paul-Linsays-iPad SpringBoard[50] <Warning>: could not save thumbnail for downloading icon: image=(null) path='/var/mobile/Library/SpringBoard/DownloadingIconImageCache/com.LinsayAssociates.CreditorsRights-6E9CCB4B-A428-4695-8758-81F74FBB404D'

Comment: Yeah, that's the same error I got.  Did you try deleting the application and rebooting like I said?

Comment: Out of desperation I made up an iTunes version of the archive.  It downloaded without any trouble to the original iPad.  Weird.

Comment: I tried the delete/reboot method several times prior to posting here.  Didn't work.  It's apparently something to do with OTA since the iTunes download was just fine.